# How does Trigger.io handle barcode scanning for different platforms?

Tags: ios, trigger.io

The docs for Trigger.io's barcode scanner (http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/modules/barcode.html) do not explicitly state how barcode scanning is handled.

From expermienting, it seems that they're using [ZXing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/) for Android via an intent call, meaning the user must download the app first. However, I'm not sure how iOS and other platforms are handled. Is the barcode functionality bundled with the app or is there another app the user must install?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you discovered on Android Trigger uses the barcode intent, if the user doesn't have ZXing installed they will be prompted to install it (most users do have some form of barcode scanner installed).

On iOS the ZXing library is built into the app, so no extra application is required.

Comment: So that means on iOS, only QR codes are allowed? ZXing website states the iOS port only supports QR codes, or does Trigger.io use a modified version of the iOS port? I think this is important information to have in the API docs.

Comment: The ZXing docs are out of date here - 1D barcodes are supported on iOS. Android might support more variations of the 1D codes, however...